# Wordpress child theme don't work properly

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I'm new in Wordpress and I'm trying to create a child theme of the Best Education theme but I get some trouble to do that. My website with the child theme don't looks the same as with the parent theme.

I created a new folder best-education-child and put two files in: style.css and functions.php.

Here is style.css :

```
/*
Theme Name: Best Education Child
Template: best-education
Text Domain: best-education-child
*/
```

And function.php :

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
?>
```

When using this code I don't get the right font and the navbar isn't displayed properly.

I also tried to link every css files of the parent theme in fuctions.php :

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/libraries/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-widget', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/libraries/custom/css/admin-widget.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/libraries/slick/css/slick.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/libraries/slick/css/slick-theme.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'customize-controls', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/libraries/custom/css/customize-controls.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'about', get_template_directory_uri() . 'inc/about/css/about.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
?>
```

Some issues are resolved, the fonts become the good one, but the navbar isn't still correctly displayed (but the navbar is differently displayed as before), content isn't in the good place and there is no way to scroll down the page. In fact that's worst.

Can anyone help with this ?

**EDIT :**

Finaly, I made the choice to change the parent theme for another one which looks similar, in this case the child creation works good.

I am reading the wordpress codex and find something that I missed and that can maybe solve the problem, haven't try it but may be the answer to the problem :

> Note: You may need to re-save your menu (Appearance > Menus, or
>   Appearance > Customize > Menus) and theme options (including
>   background and header images) after activating the child theme.

Comment: your problem is that you're trying to create child theme after configuring the parent theme. when you're activating child theme all settings of parent theme will become as default( like fresh installation of theme ).

Comment: Yes it is true the parent configs are not set on the child theme, but my problem is that the child theme don't look as the fresh installation theme. The navbar is displayed with CSS bug and the font isn't the default one. There is an issue with the CSS, certainly coming from my functions.php file but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: if you're sure that `Template: best-education` is set right, then in the functions php file there isn't any error. even without adding anything into the `functions.php` file, wordpress will load parent theme's style.css file by default. your problem may be the theme customazation. there in the parent theme may be some custom css written in the db( from theme options CSS label ), which not loading after changing theme

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when inspecting the page it appear that all the CSS is there but the dependencies are not good and this is the wrong CSS which take the priority. I just take an other theme with the same aspect and child theme works well, problem "solved".

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but using Divi theme, i wrote to support and they gave me the child theme. You can do the same or try with wordpress plugins that creates child themes. Above you have a link to child theme Divi support gave me , it works perfectly.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bCuhWvTrWXu2x3xpABFbqwpklDstW4kh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will send a message to the support.